# Album art not showing when using AudioPlaybackAgent in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, albumart, audio-playback-agent

when using the AudioPlaybackAgent in WP7 I create a track before playing it. Now when I create the track everything transfers: the file, the title, the artist, and the album, but for some reason when I navigate to the Music and Video Hub on the phone the AlbumArt never shows up.

Here's my code:

```
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack();
audioTrack.BeginEdit();
audioTrack.Source = new Uri(track.Attribute("source").Value);
audioTrack.Title = track.Attribute("title").Value;
audioTrack.Artist = track.Attribute("artist").Value;
audioTrack.Album = track.Attribute("album").Value;
audioTrack.AlbumArt = new Uri(track.Attribute("albumArt").Value);
audioTrack.EndEdit();
```

NOTE: The **track.Attribute** is just extracting the values from an xml file. I did debug this and the correct paths are in there and all data is being returned just fine. Any idea why It isn't showing up? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the image present in the isolated storage under the shared/media directory?

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.audiotrack.albumart%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

> If you copy the image file into isolated storage under the
>   shared/media directory and set this property, the album art will
>   automatically be displayed in the Now Playing tile in the Music +
>   Videos Hub.