# Setting AlbumArt of AudioTrack

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background-audio

I'm using Background Audio Player on Windows Phone 8 and I'm trying to set an album art for my audio track. As I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828118/album-art-not-showing-when-using-audioplaybackagent-in-wp7) and at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.audiotrack.albumart(v=vs.105).aspx) the image MUST be at shared/media/ - ok I've checked the image is there and I try to do:

```
AudioTrack myTrack = new AudioTrack(track.source, track.Title, track.Artist, track.Album, new Uri("shared/media/Episode29.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
```

The music starts, but there is no image. Am I doing something wrong?
I've also run [Background Audio Player Sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=219073) mentioned [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx) and I also see no image.

Comment: You've copied the files into isolated storage?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Yes, I've checked with IsolatedStorage explorer, there is directory Shared/Media and file in it - so it should work. I've also done it similar way like in MSDN example (which also doesn't show images - weird). I tried to find a solution for many hours but I've failed.