# Error 0x80070057 in BackgroundAudioPlayer

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, background-audio

Sometimes (rarely) while running my App, I get an error 0x80070057 thrown by BackgroundAudioPlayer.
 As I've observed it happens for a scenario like this:

- I start to play the song,
- I pause it,
- Wait some time - few hours (BAP with the song stays in background),
- Play the song with UVC.

Like I said - it doesn't happen always, it is not connected to particular song. It is hard to debug, what I've managed to do is to Save the error.Message to file when BAP.OnError() is fired (thus I know the error numer). I've tried to save also StackTrace but without success (it is empty).

Does anybody know what can cause this error?

Comment: FWIW, 0x80070057 means "The parameter is incorrect."

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks for the clue, I wasn't aware of that. I'm not sure but I suspect that the problem may be concerned with BAP itself - since I'm not changing any parameters.

Comment: Wrong image size as a MediaHistoryItem.ImageStream, maybe other properties of AudioTrack.

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov Thank you for the possible reason - as I think now that may be the problem. But with current SDK it is not possible to correct that (or even test), since [even MSDN example doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365048/setting-albumart-of-audiotrack). Weird is that it doesn't happen always. Waiting for WP8.1.

Comment: I'm actually talking about MediaHistoryItem.ImageStream, not about AlbumArt inside the AudioTrack. As for AudioTrack, you can take a look at http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/mpatool/a6056e5e-34bd-4098-9cd8-4ed5df611d97

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov First I thought that setting AlbumArt would also set MediaHistoryItem. But I will try to do it manually. I will give you a sign if that helped (it will probably take some time - especially testing).

Comment: Is the song stored local or being streamed? What is the audio format?

Comment: @tiwahu It is stored local. I mostly play mp3 files.