# Setting AlbumArt from isolated storage of AudioTrack

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-audio

I'm using Background Audio Player on Windows Phone 8 and I'm trying to set an album art for my audio track. As I've read here and at MSDN the image MUST be at shared/media/
image is present into isolated storage

test1

```
new Uri("Shared/Media/1.jpg")
```

test2

```
new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/Shared/Media/1.jpg")
```

but not it works, why?

Comment: Few months ago I've tried the same with the same result - [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21365048/2681948) & [MSDN one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7df817b2-7505-4414-b945-1f66662e28a7/audiotrack-and-its-albumart?forum=wpdevelop#e5f391d3-32e0-4a37-9c97-6235a05d2373). After many tries I gave up, thought I haven't tried now after some updates.

Answer (score 0):

in a Windows phone 8 control  not it works with bindings from isolated storage.
I'm used a SuperImage control of Coding4Fun Toolkit

Comment: Can you say something more about your solution? Where do you use this SuperImage control? Can you see the image in UVC?

Comment: my problem was to see the cover image in the app